# bash script to recursively delete files from folders which end in even numbers

Tags: regex, bash

I have a nested folder hierarchy containing hundreds of files in the format [a-z].[0-9].h5

where [a-z] can be any length alphanumeric, [0-9] can be any number of digits but always a number, and the extension is fixed, h5.

e.g.

- model1_weights.1.h5
- model354_weights.64.h5

etc.

To save space I'd like to delete all of the EVEN files

e.g. these remain:

- model1_weights.1.h5
- model1_weights.37.h5
- model1_weights.185.h5

but these go

- model1_weights.0.h5
- model1_weights.32.h5
- model1_weights.184.h5

I know how to do this in python, traverse all the directories, split at the dots, check, and delete. But I feel like this should be possible with a single bash command with rm -rf (or find) and regex. Is this possible?

NOTE: In the future to save even more space I may like to delete every 2 out of 3 files. i.e. general pattern is KEEP only if (i % n ==1) where i is the index of the file, and n is an arbitrary number (e.g. 2 or 3)

Comment: You better split your question in 2: how traverse files tree and how to check if file names ends with even number.

Comment: I was (perhaps incorrectly) assuming that rm -rf (or find) would do the traversing, I would just need to pass the correct filter to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
shopt -s globstar failglob
rm -rf **/model*_weights.*{0,2,4,6,8}.h5
```

I would change `rm -rf` to `echo` before you run it! Alternatively, `printf '%s\n'` would give a clearer output.

The shell option `globstar` allows you to use `**` to do a recursive match. `failglob` ensures that the command isn't run if nothing matches the pattern.

Comment: `find` too looks like a tempting choice here.

Comment: thx!. one little nag. when I do echo, there is no newline making it very difficult to parse the info. is it possible to add a new line?

Comment: @memo if you use `printf` instead of `echo` as I suggested, each directory will be printed on a separate line.